# Who knows King is powerless?

Tags: one-punch-man

Ok, Saitama found out King is powerless. Do other people know about it? How about the other heroes he hangs out with? (Genos, Fubuki, etc.)

Comment: Saitama does, but as @Kenichi-san said above, the others might have an idea about it. Another question would be if he really is powerless? At the moment he seems useless, but have you seen some normal character that emits so much heat and pressure, just from being afraid. Also, he is pretty built-up. I really think it's some hidden power that needs a trigger to manifest, just as how it happened with Saitama in his early days.

Answer (score 1):

It seems only Saitama does. We don't know about other heroes Genos envisioned all the heroes including King fighting together so it seems that he doesn't think of King as a weakling. King asked to train under Bang and it does seem that Bang had got suspicious of King but it still seems like nobody knows of King's weakness.

Comment: I think that is correct as many of the heros have said they wanted to see him fight.

Answer (score 1):

From now, as we saw in the last episode, we can suppose that Saitama, Genos, Bang, Bomb know about King's true power. 
They saw the entire scene, with King shouting "Saitama-shiiii" and asking for Saitama to help.

Reference : Episode 12 Season 2

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guTCB7rvpss

Comment: I am not sure they saw what happened only the aftermath as the monster that Saitama helped defeat blocked the view of the others and they where not able to see or hear what happened. At least that is what I remember from the manga.